# iOS How to create a UIView that blur contents under itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, blur

I have a `UIView` that partially cover some contents and I would like apply a blur effect exactly like the iOS Notification Center.

I'm not looking for a way to apply blur on `UIImage`, but on `UIView` with other contents (`UIView`, `UIButton`, ecc) under it.

[image]

Ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: This class should provide what you are looking for:

https://github.com/JagCesar/iOS-blur

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIToolbar* bgToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:myView.frame];
bgToolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
[myView.superview insertSubview:bgToolbar belowSubview:myView];
```

just past from an other answer how ever i use toolbar in my projects and works perfect, i am using alpha=0.98 [image]

Comment: That will not provide blurred effect.

Answer (score -1):

First change the UIView into an UIImage.
You can use the following as a category of UIView.

```
@implementation UIView (ConvertToUIImage)

- (UIImage *)asImage {
    NSAssert(self, @"Do not use this method on nil instance of UIView.");
    if (!self) return 0;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, YES, 0);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.frame afterScreenUpdates:NO];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSAssert(image, @"Image must not be nil at this point.");
    return image;
}

@end
```

Next you need to blur the UIImage, there is a related question here [Creating a blur effect in iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432773/creating-a-blur-effect-in-ios7)

Finally, use the UIImage as a background.

Comment: I have a `UIView` and I need `UIView`, as I wrote in the question I'm not looking for a way to apply blur to `UIImage`

Comment: Look at the screenshot you posted. The home screen can be thought of as viewA and the notification-center as viewB. The idea is to create a UIImage representation of viewA, before showing viewB. Then blur the UIImage, and finally add it as background of viewB. Now if you present viewB it will appear to be transparent on top of viewA, where viewA is blurred - just like in the posted screenshot. The details are laid out in the book Programming iOS 7 by Matt Neuburg, among other similiar tricks. Did I misunderstand your requirements?