# Very slow UIImage blurring on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, blur

I would like to apply blur on my image view. I have this code for blurring:

```
- (UIImage *)applyBlurOnImage: (UIImage *)imageToBlur withRadius: (CGFloat)blurRadius
{
    CIImage *originalImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage: imageToBlur.CGImage];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName: @"CIGaussianBlur" keysAndValues: kCIInputImageKey, originalImage, @"inputRadius", @(blurRadius), nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = filter.outputImage; CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CGImageRef outImage = [context createCGImage: outputImage fromRect: [outputImage extent]];
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage: outImage];
}
```

But blurring happens very slow for screenshot of my `UIView` on iPad.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fast blur on iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271016/fast-blur-on-ios)

Comment: You can try https://github.com/lukabernardi/LBBlurredImage

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apple released code at WWDC that does what you need.

It is a category on `UIImage` and uses the `Accelerate` framework for fast image processing.
If you have a developer account you can grab the `UIImage` category [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=wwdc_2013/wwdc_2013_sample_code/ios_uiimageeffects.zip).

Comment: Did they really release it at WWDC? I remember it wasn't really there for quite some time after the presentation (I think the blur was only on the UIToolbar or whatnot..). But hey, that's awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://github.com/radi/LiveFrost) library. It is fairly new and quite fast. Remember that blur is either way quite nasty thing for the device to process, so it won't be zen-like, but it's very good.

OR - you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432773/creating-a-blur-effect-in-ios7) question that has some high quality answers.