# Blur UILabel in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilabel, uiblureffect

How can I blur the text of UILabel?

UIBlurEffectView is not blurring the text but whole background.

Can you please let me know how can I achieve this?

Thank you,

Comment: Set alpha value of your label like yourLabelName.alpha = 0.5(the amount you want to blue) the label

Comment: @IraniyaNaynesh this will not blur the label, it will just fade out :P

Comment: In that case label don't have any kind of "Blur feature" so either create CATextlayer or subclass the label and update draw method

Comment: Hey nirav this link can be useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303090/how-to-blur-uilabel-text/30305200#30305200

Comment: https://github.com/mkoehnke/AnimatedBlurLabel might be useful...

Comment: @AhmadF, it is not working with tableViewCell

Comment: @nirav Please take a look at this answer I provided with a custom UILabel which can achieve the blur effect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224908/3564632

Answer (score 0):

As it was an interesting question, I looked up in UILabel documentation. There doesn't seem to be a method responsible for text drawing only, which could be overriden.

So my way of solving your problem would be this:

1. Subclass a UIView with separate drawing methods for background and text.
2. In the text drawing method, draw the text to an off-screen image.
3. Then apply blur filter (Core Image framework) to that image.
4. Draw the blurred image over the background (possibly your subclass may have 2 UIViews: one for the back and another for the text).

The obvious drawback of all this is that this custom subclass would miss all the features of attributed text and multiple-line division of the UILabel.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve blurring just the text, without background, by using `CATextLayer` instead of `UILabel`. `CALayer` has a `contentsScale` property, and if you set it to value lower than screen's scale, you will achieve blur effect

```
let view = UIView()
let textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.string = "yourText"
textLayer.contentsScale = 0.5 // lower number means more blurry text
view.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
```

`contentsScale` defaults to 1.0, but for clear rendering of text it must be assigned the value of `UIScreen.main.scale`, which is 2.0 for most iPhones, with iPhone X being notable example with the value of 3.0. The lower the value, the more text will be blurred.

Comment: I have UILabel, I can not use CATextLayer as autoresizing cell