# Why does UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext return nil after UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-image

I am following a code example to make a blurred UILabel, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62224908/2226315.

My requirement is to make the label on blur after label initialization instead of calling the `blur` method at runtime. However, when I try to call `blur` after label gets initialized the value returned from `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` is `nil` hence having a "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
print("DEBUG: bounds.size", bounds.size)
self.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!) // <- return nil
var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
print("DEBUG: image image", image)
```

I tried adding the code in all the following places individually, the context can be fetched now however it does not generate the blur effect as expected.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.blur()
}

// OR
    
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    self.blur()
}
```

Full code snippet,

```
class BlurredLabel: UILabel {

    func blur(_ blurRadius: Double = 2.5) {        
        let blurredImage = getBlurryImage(blurRadius)
        let blurredImageView = UIImageView(image: blurredImage)
        blurredImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blurredImageView.tag = 100
        blurredImageView.contentMode = .center
        blurredImageView.backgroundColor = .white
        addSubview(blurredImageView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            blurredImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            blurredImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func unblur() {
        subviews.forEach { subview in
            if subview.tag == 100 {
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }

    private func getBlurryImage(_ blurRadius: Double = 2.5) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(),
            let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur") else {
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return nil
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        blurFilter.setDefaults()

        blurFilter.setValue(CIImage(image: image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blurFilter.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)

        var convertedImage: UIImage?
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        if let blurOutputImage = blurFilter.outputImage,
            let cgImage = context.createCGImage(blurOutputImage, from: blurOutputImage.extent) {
            convertedImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        }

        return convertedImage
    }
}
```

**REFERENCE**

- [Add blur view to label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224738/add-blur-view-to-label/62224908#62224908)
- [How to blur UILabel text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30303090/how-to-blur-uilabel-text)

**UPDATE**

Usage based on "Eugene Dudnyk" answer

```
definitionLabel = BlurredLabel()
definitionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
definitionLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
definitionLabel.textColor = UIColor(named: "text")
definitionLabel.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text"
definitionLabel.clipsToBounds = false
definitionLabel.isBluring = true
```

Comment: Did you check that `CGRectIsEmpty(bounds) == false`?

Comment: A simpler approach might be to add an UIVisualEffectView as a subview of your label and just hide it whenever you need. You can attatch an UIBlurEffect to the UIVisualEffectView to get the desired effect

Comment: @Pastre I tried to put the label behind a UIVisualEffectView however it does not look as good as a blurred created via CoreImage.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk i just checked the bounds and it is empty after the label initialization. can you share with me if what's the right place to get the context?

Comment: You shouldn't even draw anything if the bounds are empty. Label takes no space on the screen in this case, and it will get the non-empty bounds later. Just don't create the context until it gets the bounds.

Comment: @EugeneDudnyk thanks for your response, can you share with me how can I know when the view will get its bounds, so I can call `blur` there.

Comment: @Metropolis maybe override the `layoutSubviews()` method and there call `blur()`

Comment: @Pastre it causes an infinity loop by adding `self.blur()` inside `layoutSubviews`

Comment: @Metropolis In your view controller, you can override `viewDidLayoutSubviews` and there call `view.blur()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a better solution - instead of retrieving the blurred image, just let the label blur itself.

When you need it to be blurred, set `label.isBlurring = true`.
Also, this solution is better for performance, because it reuses the same context and does not need the image view.

```swift
@IBDesignable
class BlurredLabel: UILabel {
    @IBInspectable
    public var isBlurring: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable
    public var blurRadius: Double = 2.5 {
        didSet {
            blurFilter?.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        }
    }

    lazy var blurFilter: CIFilter? = {
        let blurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
        blurFilter?.setDefaults()
        blurFilter?.setValue(blurRadius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        return blurFilter
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        configure()
    }

    func configure() {
        layer.isOpaque = false
        layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = true
        layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
        layer.contentsGravity = .center
        isOpaque = false
        isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        contentMode = .redraw
    }

    override func display(_ layer: CALayer) {
        let bounds = layer.bounds
        guard !bounds.isEmpty && bounds.size.width < CGFloat(UINT16_MAX) else {
            layer.contents = nil
            return
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.bounds.size, layer.isOpaque, layer.contentsScale)
        if let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            self.layer.draw(in: ctx)
        
            var image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()?.cgImage
            if isBlurring, let cgImage = image {
                blurFilter?.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: cgImage), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
                let ciContext = CIContext(cgContext: ctx, options: nil)
                if let blurOutputImage = blurFilter?.outputImage,
                   let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(blurOutputImage, from: blurOutputImage.extent) {
                    image = cgImage
                }
            }
            layer.contents = image
        }
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, can you have any suggestions for UITextView for the above code?

Comment: @KishanBhatiya if you use text view just to show links, you can use BlurredLabel instead, and set `attributedText` to it like it is described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1256887/create-tap-able-links-in-the-nsattributedstring-of-a-uilabel

Comment: thank you for the quick response, Using text view I'm not showing any link but attributed string. how can we do this with the text view?  you can [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428968/blur-uitextviews-text)

Comment: @KishanBhatiya Text view uses private sub view to display text, and that’s the view that should be blurred in your scenario. I don’t think you can achieve it without using private apis

Comment: Using `VisualEffectView()` i can but the whole text view, not text view's text and it also shows edges as you can see in my question mentioned above in the comment. Have you any suggestions or thoughts for `VisualEffectView()` then it will be helpful

Comment: @KishanBhatiya no, I can’t help here because it requires research of the possibilities or building text view from scratch

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you @EugeneDudnyk

Comment: How do you unblur at runtime in this case?

Comment: @yaozhang Set `label.isBlurring = false`

Comment: Thanks but it is broken if label is added inside xib (for example in cell)

Comment: @Gargo it wasn't a requirement of the initial question. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Transformed @EugeneDudnyk answer to UIView extension so it can be used also with TextView.

```
extension UIView {
    struct BlurableKey {
        static var blurable = "blurable"
    }
    
    func blur(radius: CGFloat) {
        guard superview != nil else { return }
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: frame.width, height: frame.height), false, 1)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        guard
            let blur = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur"),
            let image = image
        else {
            return
        }
  
        blur.setValue(CIImage(image: image), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
        blur.setValue(radius, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
        
        let ciContext  = CIContext(options: nil)
        let boundingRect = CGRect(
            x:0,
            y: 0,
            width: frame.width,
            height: frame.height
        )
        
        guard
            let result = blur.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as? CIImage,
            let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(result, from: boundingRect)
        else {
            return
        }
                
        let blurOverlay = UIImageView()
        blurOverlay.frame = boundingRect
        blurOverlay.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
        blurOverlay.contentMode = .left
        
        addSubview(blurOverlay)
     
        objc_setAssociatedObject(
            self,
            &BlurableKey.blurable,
            blurOverlay,
            objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN
        )
    }
    
    func unBlur() {
        guard
            let blurOverlay = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &BlurableKey.blurable) as? UIImageView
        else {
            return
        }
        
        blurOverlay.removeFromSuperview()
        
        objc_setAssociatedObject(
            self,
            &BlurableKey.blurable,
            nil,
            objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN
        )
    }
    
    var isBlurred: Bool {
        return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &BlurableKey.blurable) is UIImageView
    } 
}
```